# Server 2003 Strange AD Domain Name

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm working on a site that has an odd domain name and I think it may be why I am having trouble establishing a trust.

The domain is named as follows (2003 DC):

- NETBIOS Domain Name: CITY
- DNS Domain Name: CITY.COMPANYNAME

This domain functionality level is 2000 Native and the forest functionality level is in 2000.

I'm trying to establish a trust with a 2008 R2 DC hosting a domain as follows:

- NETBIOS Domain Name: COMPANYNAME
- DNS Domain Name: COMPANYNAME.local

This domain functionality level is 2008R2 and the forest functionality level is 2008R2.

My question is two part. Will raising the first domain (CITY.COMPANYNAME) to 2003 domain and forest functionality levels be ok with it's odd name? Could the odd naming be what is causing my difficulties in creating the trusts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using city.companyname is no less "bad" than your domain using .local. Both are made up non-reserved TLDs and neither of you should be using either.

That said, I think you're barking up the wrong tree. Neither of those should be an issue, your problem most likely lies elsewhere.

---

> Will raising the first domain (CITY.COMPANYNAME) to 2003 domain and forest functionality levels be ok with it's odd name?

Yes.

> Could the odd naming be what is causing my difficulties in creating the trusts?

No.

Comment: Agreed on both counts but you get what you inherit sometimes for the short term. I have this fixed now. I found an object in the CITY.COMPANYNAME domain that was using the same NETBIOS name as the NETBIOS Domain Name of the COMPANYNAME.local domain name. Going to give you the correct though for confirming that my world won't blow up if I decide to raise the functionality level.

Answer (score 1):

The domain names are ok. First try to ping to each domain from the other domain, if that works then post your error message here so we can help you.